# how to set single quote in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to set javascript variable with single quote. How it is possible. I am passing value to my function as parameter. and I am using this value to retrieve value of checkbox. So my problem is that if I am alerting value then it give me 'user' instead of 'sanjay' Here 'sanjay' is my value which is I am passing to parameter. And this will use to retrieve value of checkbox document.getElementById.

```
function single(user){

                var abc = '\' user \'';
                alert(abc);
                return false;
                var chksingle = document.getElementById(abc).checked;
                alert(chksingle);
                return false;
                if (userlist() === false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {           
                        document.tallyexport.method = "post";
                        document.tallyexport.action = "checksingle.php";
                        document.tallyexport.submit();          
                }
            }
```

Comment: `var abc = " ' "+ user +" ' " `

Comment: no need to do that just pass user directly instant of abc in 'document.getElementById'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use string concatenation.  The way you are doing it right now has `user` as part of the actual string, not using the variable.

```
var abc = "' " + user + " '"
```

Comment: Also tell me that how to retrieve value of checkbox. I am unable to get value?

Comment: Is the id that the checkbox has `sanjay` or `' sanjay '`?

Comment: id="sanjay" this is my id I am using manually then it is retrieving but dynamically it is not retrieving

Comment: `var chksingle = document.getElementById(user).checked;`
I believe you want that as your id does not have actual quotes in it based on what you typed, it's just that you are giving it as a string.  User being passed in should already be a string so there is no need to wrap it in quotes.
If my assumption is right, your checkbox will look like this in html:
`<input type="checkbox" id="sanjay" value="sanjay">`